# Failed audit in late answers

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, late-answers

So, I just failed an audit in the Late Answers queue by clicking 'No Action Needed'.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4351344

In the interests of learning, what should I have flagged this as? Yes, it's short and sweet, and technically probably a horrible solution. But it's very much 'an answer' - especially so as it was posted by the OP, it was a solution which worked for them. And what they have done is clear.

I've always thought that the main job of these queues was to catch 'non-answers' - and low quality/technically bad answers like this should just be subjected to down votes? Should I have flagged this as 'very low quality'? The point of the answer is pretty clear...

Comment: Which, yes, doesn't make it such a good answer, but doesn't stop it being an answer, does it?

Comment: What feature are you, exactly, requesting?

Comment: Sorry! Was going to add in a feature request too (supplying the close vote reason for a failed review audit - rather than a compulsory "I Understand" buttons) but then decided it would be better for a separate question. (And then found the wealth of other, similar failed review audit requests, and decided posting wasn't worth the effort.) Must have forgotten to remove the tag. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If you feel it should be downvoted *then why didn't you downvote it*.  That's an action in the queue.  You decided to take no action.
2. It's *not* answering the question.  It's merely the person that asked the question *responding to another answer* to say the equivalent of "thanks, it worked".  This shouldn't be posted as an answer.  Flagging it as NAA is appropriate.  It has since been deleted for this reason.

Comment: 1. Valid point. 2. Now you mention it, I can potentially see it coming from that way. I read "Got it" as "I've figured it out", not "I get what you're saying" - as you seem to have done. Fair enough, I'll take that one - thanks. 

Completely unrelated, had I 'downvoted' then clicked 'I'm Done', would I have passed the review? I didn't as downvoting also has connotations of an answer being wrong - which it isn't.

Comment: @Chris Yes, you'd have passed the audit.  Downvoting is for answers that aren't *useful*, not for answers that are strictly wrong.  Poor quality answers should be downvoted even if they aren't technically incorrect.

Comment: @chris if it is technically horrible, it's wrong even if it works. If you add two numbers by building a string with a plus inside and evaling it, I'll downvote.

Comment: Thanks both - I'll endeavour to downvote more whilst reviewing! ;)